# How to integrate sqlite3 in Sveltekit?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, better-sqlite3, sveltekit

I have been using sqlite3 for most of my fullstack applications (node/express, django/drf + svelte on the front end as the consumer of the api endpoints) and have been trying to figure out how to integrate sqlite3.

Comment: @AnilBhattarai Could you remove the guide part out of the question and post it as an accepted answer?
That would fit the stackoverlow model better. (Right now it is marked as an unanswered question)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `better-sqlite3` is a *synchronous* library.

I notice you're using `await` with `better-sqlite3`. Removing `await` might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`index.json.ts` didn't work for me for some reason. I had to change it to `list.json.ts`.

Also, they changed the endpoint handler to all uppercase GET [in this discussion](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5359).